# Leer una fecha de Excel en java

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

tengo el siguiente problema, si alguien me puede orientar.

Quiero leer una fecha de un Excel (.xlsx) con Apache POI. La fecha que ingreso es 5/9/2023

```
XSSFCell cFecha = fila.getCell(1);                  
double d = (Double) cFecha.getNumericCellValue();       
Date f = DateUtil.getJavaDate(d);
```

Y la salida es:

Tue Mar 03 00:00:00 ART 5276
Sat Mar 13 00:00:00 ART 5328

He probado varios métodos que están acá y me sigue dando el mismo error. Sobre todo me da dos fechas distintas cuando es la misma fecha que se ingresa.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás seguro de que la celda tiene una fecha, puedes intentar convertirla de la siguiente manera:

```
if (cFecha.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cFecha)) {
        Date date = cFecha.getDateCellValue();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió bastante.